# Client per MicroService vs Generic Client | Who is responsible for microservice client?

Tags: distributed-computing, microservices

I have a microService architecture with 10 microServices and each of those provides a client. Inside of that client which is managed/controlled by microService team we just receive the parameters and pass them to a generic http invoker which receives the endpoint and N params and then does the call.
All microService use http and web api (I guess technology doesn't matter).

For me doesn't make sense to be the microService team to provide a client, should be the responsibility of the consumer, if they want to create some abstractions or invoke it directly is their problem, not a microService problem. And the way I see a web API is as a contract. So I think we should delete all clients (pass responsibility to consumers) on the microService side and create a service layer on the consumer's side that uses the generic invoker to reach the endpoints.

The image below represents all components where the **red line defines** the boundaries, **who is responsible for what**:

- The gateway has Adapter Layer
- Adapter Layer references the microService client package
- MicroService client package references Generic HTTP invoker package
  [image]

The other side of that is because we might have N number of consumers and they are all repeating the code of the client. And if the microService provides a client, we have a unique/central place to control that.

**Which approach is correct? Is the client a responsability of the microService or the consumer?**

This is an internal product.

Comment: how are u identifying the client details ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a similar setup at work, with several microservices (~40) and a dozen teams. I was asked the same question several times, and my answer is **the consumer is responsible for consuming**. If the API works as designed and expected, there is no point in making the providing team responsible for anything.

The team that provides the service (team a), **may** provide a client, if they want (in doubt, without warranty). The consuming team (team B) **may** use the client if **they** want (taking all the risks included).
The only contract should be the API, everything else should be a goodie a team may provide on top. If team a **has** to provide a client, why do they provide an api at all then?

Given that both teams are loosely coupled and may use different technologies (or e.g. different spring framework versions), providing a client library to the other team proves to bring more problems than solve any. In a Java+spring-boot world e.g. you get into dependency problems very fast, especially if you include several clients from different service providing teams that evolve differently in time.

And even worse: what if the client-library of team A makes the system of team B unstable and introduces bugs? Who is responsible to fix that now?

If you want to reduce the work needed for your consuming teams because re-coding the client is so much work, your API may be to complex and/or your microservice may be no more microservice at all.
Imagine using HATEOAS on a restful API - writing a client for that is just a few lines of code, even with included API-Browser, Documentation and whatnot. See e.g. spring-rest-docs, hal-browser, swagger and various other technologies that make reading/browsing/documenting an API and implementing a client a breeze.

Above cases are described with two teams, imagine that with 10. We had a "client library" provided by one team, used by 4 other teams. You can guess how fast it became a complete mess until it was just deleted :)

Comment: In addition, if a team chooses a different language than the norm, should the team provide an additional client in a language they may not know? It's best to provide good documentation and a small clean API than a client.